# Pipe and Channels in modelica

Tags: fluid, modelica, channel, openmodelica

I am trying to model a microchannel for fluid transport in openmodelica. The channel is non-circular though. I am not an expert in modelica, so if i may ask, from where can i start ? is the static and the dynamic pipes in the fluid library suitable for my purpose with some modifications ?

Here's the link of how the channel looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7opdu6dwnvqfsfc/pipe.png?dl=0

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to model non-circular pipes with the MSL, but probably you can break it down to a circular pipe that has the same properties as your non-circular one.

I am no expert on fluid dynamics, but if your current can be assumed to always be orthogonal to the cross section of the pipe (no chaotic behavior) you should be able to linearly map the cross section area to a diameter of a circular pipe and use that instead.